# Jquery mobile- Multipage template validation using jquery validate.js

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

On click of next button, the validation occurs for current page and on click of submit, validation occurs for all pages using

`var validator = $("#frmAddstore").data('validator');`

`validator.settings.ignore = "";`

Now i find problem on setting the focus to the page which is hidden. How to navigate the page where the error?

I can get the error element, If its in the current page then i can set focus thru `$(this).find(":input.error:first").focus()`. If its hidden page am not able to set the focus as well as i dont know the pageid or divid to changepage to that.

But i can get the id of the element using `$(this).find(":input.error:first").attr("id")` Is there any way to get the div id from the element id?

I have created a jsfiddle to show the issue. [jsfiddle.net/U4RPf/14](http://jsfiddle.net/U4RPf/14/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the page with the error

```
var idErrorPage = $(this).find(":input.error:first").parents("div:jqmData(role='page')").attr("id")
```

Change to that page

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#" + idErrorPage );
```

I have created a jsbin, it does not use validate.js but it should show you what you need to know http://jsbin.com/awaluw/edit#html

Complete Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/U4RPf/15

Comment: I can get the error element. If its in the current page then i can set focus thru <br>`$(this).find(":input.error:first").focus()`. If its hidden page am not able to set the focus as well as i dont know the pageid or divid to changepage to that.

Comment: But i can get the id of the element using `$(this).find(":input.error:first").attr("id")`. Can we get the div id from the element id?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or jsbin of your current situation?

Comment: I have updated my answer again and created a jsbin with a working example for you.

Comment: This one works http://jsfiddle.net/U4RPf/15/ I think you just missed my last update.